# Vue Dynamic V-For Show and Hide div

Tags: javascript, vue.js, dynamic, vuejs2

I would like to show one div and hide another one when i click on it.
What happens though is: I have a list of Users, each user has an icon next to its name. Clicking on one icon changes it for every user (because on click on an icon it should hide it and show another icon).
So how can i manage to differentiate them?
Info: My console log works it shows different users, but how do I manage to differentiate the v-show directive?

```
    <template>
  <span>
    <span class="userListContent" v-for="user in this.userResults" :key="user.id">
      <a :href="'/profile/'+user.id" target="blank">{{user.name}}</a>
      <i v-show="visibleBefore" @click="visibleAfter = true" class="far fa-plus"></i>
      <i v-show="visibleAfter" class="far fa-check-circle"></i>
      <input type="checkbox" />
    </span>
  </span>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["userResults"],
  data: function() {
    return {
        visibleBefore: true,
        visibleAfter: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    change(user) {
      console.log(user);
      //   this.visibleBefore = false;
      //   this.visibleAfter = true;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

I also tried to have a user object in data function but this seems to be completely wrong.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way is to create a `UserListItem` component that receives the user as a prop:

```
<template v-for="user in this.userResults" :key="user.id">
  <user-list-item :user="user"/>
</template>
```

Then internally you can have a `boolean` that will toggle the icon like this:

```
// UserListItem.vue
<template>
  <span class="userListContent">
    <a :href="'/profile/'+user.id" target="blank">{{user.name}}</a>
    <i @click="showPlusIcon = !showPlusIcon" class="far" :class="iconId"></i>
    <input type="checkbox" />
  </span>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      user: {
        type: Object,
        required: true
      }
    },
    data () {
      return {
        showPlusIcon: true
      }
    },
    computed: {
      iconId () {
        return this.showPlusIcon ? 'fa-plus' : 'fa-check-circle'
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id">
      {{user.name}}
      <template v-if="user.visible">
        <button @click="onClick(user.id)">Show</button>
        {{user.email}}
      </template>
      <template v-if="! user.visible">
        <button @click="onClick(user.id)">Hide</button>
        {{user.phonr}}
      </template>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onClick(id) {
      this.users.map(user => {
        if(id = user.id) {
          user.visible = !!! user.visible
        }
      })
    },
  }
}
</script>
```

You need to put the `visible function` in your database or you can push them in the `data object` as another field. Then you can toggle the `visible`.

Comment: `users` is a prop, it should not be mutated, it is a bad practice to do that, also he just wants to toggle an icon, not remove the user

Comment: the above code don't mutate the the state of the object but change only the property of vissible. Also it is accessing the `props` property.

Comment: That's right, if you only mutate the property then the component won't render that change. It will keep the old value.

Comment: @EderChrono The thing is I only change the `DOM` not the actual state of the variable. So if the value of the `visible = true` then I change it to `false` through the method it change but when you refresh, it will return back to its original value

Answer (score 1):

You can use v-if inside v-for
the answer @code-for-money gave is great but he could use v-else instead of writing v-if twice.

```
v-if="user.visible"
v-else
```

check out the [documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html#Conditional-Groups-with-v-if-on-lt-template-gt) it explains all kinda possibility

Answer (score 0):

```
<template>
  <div>
    <!-- parent[0] -->
    <div v-for="user in users" :key="user.id" :ref="`div-${user.id}`">
      <!-- children[0] -->
      <div>
        {{user.name}}
      </div>

      <!-- children[1] -->
      <div> 
        <button @click="onClick(user.id, 'show')">Show</button>
        {{user.email}}
      </div>

      <!-- children[2] -->
      <div>
        <button @click="onClick(user.id, 'hide')">Hide</button>
        {{user.phone}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    onClick(id, sts) {
      if(sts == 'show'){
        this.$refs['div-'+id][0].children[0].hidden = false;
        this.$refs['div-'+id][0].children[1].hidden = true;
        this.$refs['div-'+id][0].children[2].hidden = false; 
      }
      else {
        this.$refs['div-'+id][0].children[0].hidden = true;
        this.$refs['div-'+id][0].children[1].hidden = false;
        this.$refs['div-'+id][0].children[2].hidden = true; 
      }

      console.log(this.$refs['div-'+id]); // You can find all element here
    },
  }
}
</script>
```